# How to remove NA's from a kableExtra kbl table?

Tags: r, kable, kableextra

When I run this code:

```
library(kableExtra)

table %>%
  kbl(caption ="Table 3: Data for Difference Equation Estimation.",col.names = c("Location",
                           "Year",
                           "Price",
                           "Per Capita Quantity",
                           "$\\Delta{P}$",
                           "$\\Delta{Q}$")) %>%
  kable_styling(full_width = F, position = "left")
```

I get the following:

[image]

How can I remove the NAs?

Comment: You should provide a sample of your data (i.e., what you have shown in the image) as code so that others can quickly and easily recreate your data. In this case, you should have run `dput(table)` in your R session and copy/paste the output in your post.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`knitr::kable()` is the foundation of `kableExtra::kbl()`. If you look at the help documentation for `knitr::kable()` it says:

> Missing values (NA) in the table are displayed as NA by default. If you want to display them with other characters, you can set the option knitr.kable.NA, e.g. options(knitr.kable.NA = '') to hide NA values.

Therefore you might try:

```
options(knitr.kable.NA = '')

table %>%
  kbl(caption = "Table 3: Data for Difference Equation Estimation.",
      col.names = c("Location",
                    "Year",
                    "Price",
                    "Per Capita Quantity",
                    "$\\Delta{P}$",
                    "$\\Delta{Q}$")) %>%
  kable_styling(full_width = F, 
                position = "left")
```